# Want to change text of TextView from other activity?

Tags: android, textview

i am currently designing a **ebook reader** app as my project, i am having a problem in changing text of the **textview** from other activity.

Contents of my project,

**Activity 1** contains two buttons and when **button1** is clicked "Some Text" Should appear and when  **button2** is clicked "Some Other Text" sholud appear in a **TextView1** which is in **Activity2**.

i mean the text should appear in TextView1 only. there is no other textview. okay.

please solve my problem with a simple code example.

Sorry for any mistakes in the question as it is my first attempt to really ask a question on internet.

Thank You

Comment: please clear out,is your only textview in activity2 and two buttons are in activity1.is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know you cannot access the UI component of2nd activity while being in first activity. so the best way is to pass the value through putExtra method of intents and then set it to textview in the oncreate of 2nd activity by getting it. here below is link which shows this method

http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/

Answer (score 0):

You can not set text on another activity. Pass the value to the next activity using intent then set the text after retrive from intent on Activity2's onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you know about the concept of SharedPreferences in android. Using that,you can fulfill this requirement.It is a global place where you can set its value from anywhere in you app and use anywhere in the same app wherever needed!

In Activity1,

```
SharedPreference s_pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor edit=s_pref.edit();

button1.setOnClick....()
{
     ... onClick()
     {
         edit.putString("textview_text","some text");
         edit.commit();
         /* you can start activity from here

         Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class); 
         startActivity(intent);

         */
         //even if you don't start activity from here,text changed would be reflected in textView1 when activity2 is loded
     }
}

button2.setOnClick....()
{
     ... onClick()
     {
         edit.putString("textview_text","some other text");
         edit.commit();
         /* you can start activity from here

         Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class); 
         startActivity(intent);

         */
         //even if you don't start activity from here,text changed would be reflected in textView1 when activity2 is loded
     }
}
```

in Activity2,

```
...
SharedPreference s_pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor edit=s_pref.edit();

String text=s_pref.getString("textview_text", "default text");
textView1.setText(text);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey its pretty simple if you want to show text on `textview` which is on another `activity` then pass the values with the help of `PutExtras` and get that values with the help of `getExtras` use `Intent` to call another activity

See sample code to pass values from one activity to another

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Insert.this,Select_msg.class);
    i.putExtra("name", name.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("emailid", emailid.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("contact", contactno.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
```

Select_msg.class

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
    name=i.getStringExtra("name");
    email = i.getStringExtra("emailid");
    cntct = i.getStringExtra("contact");
```

Hope it will work for you.and just set that values which are in variables to `textview`.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use a class say `MyText()` in which you can set and reset text or any other property of the text view.

say if you have a method `setTextView(String text)` and another method say `getText()` and a global variable `textVal`
the first method will set the `textVal = text` ie the value that is send as a parameter the second will return the `textVal`.
Now you can set the text from any where and get the value from any where,  just user `setText(MyText.getText)`

Hope this will solve your problem, please do drop a comment if Iam wrong..