# Exception while tried to set a Text on a TextView after creating an Object from Activity

Tags: android

I got stuck yesterday on programming an android app.
First of all, i solved my problem by sending an broadcast intent and react on this. But please, could you help me to unterstand the issue:

I try to update an TextView:

```
public void setProgressBarState(String daten) {
    try {

    txt.setText(daten);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(getPackageName(), daten, e);  
    }
    //progressBarHandler.sendMessage(progressBarHandler.obtainMessage(0, 0, 0,daten));
}
```

(String daten) - this String coming from a service, wich listen on a BluetoothSocket. A MessageHandler send the received data to setProgressBarState method:

```
public void onCreate() {
    dataHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String daten=(String) msg.obj;
            //Toast.makeText(BluetoothService.this, daten, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            RemoteControl remote = new RemoteControl();
            remote.setProgressBarState(daten);
            Intent intent = new Intent("DataAvialable");
            intent.putExtra("DATA", daten);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).sendBroadcastSync(intent);



        }
    };



}
```

(You can see, I solved my Problem by using Broadcast...) 
When debugging, I see a NullPointerException when "txt.setText(Daten)" is processed.

I tried to do

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TextView2);
```

before, but then I get an InvocationTargetException.

I think it is a really easy thing, but sorry, I was not able to solve this (only with my broadcast)... Please can anyone tell me why it is not possible to set the text in the TxextView...

Sorry for my english, I will answer any question, if something is not clear.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Hope this helps....

```
> 04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:123)
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at com.example.bluecomm.RemoteControl.setProgressBarState(RemoteControl.java:117)
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at com.example.bluecomm.BluetoothService$1.handleMessage(BluetoothService.java:67)
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
04-26 13:23:34.279: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sorry, it seems iam not really able to framt right...
here is XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".BlueCommMain" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/vol_Mute"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vol_Up"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:text="@string/Vol_Mute_Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/vol_Up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:text="@string/Vol_Up_Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/vol_Down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vol_Up"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vol_Mute"
    android:text="@string/Vol_Down_Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vol_Down"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vol_Down"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:text="Aktuelle Lautstärke:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

an this is my Activity

```
    ackage com.example.bluecomm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

public class RemoteControl extends Activity {
String mac = null;
Context ctx;
ProgressBar progress;
Handler progressBarHandler;
TextView txt;
BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(getPackageName(), "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.volume_remote);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle daten = intent.getExtras();
        mac = daten.getString("MAC");
        //progress=new ProgressBar(RemoteControl.this);
        progress=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        final Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);






        Button btn_Vol_Up = (Button) findViewById (R.id.vol_Up);
        btn_Vol_Up.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                Intent service = new Intent(v.getContext(), BluetoothService.class);
                service.putExtra("MAC", mac);
                service.putExtra("MESSAGE", "VOL_UP");

                vib.vibrate(30);
                startService(service);

            }});

        Button btn_Vol_Down = (Button) findViewById (R.id.vol_Down);
        btn_Vol_Down.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                Intent service = new Intent(v.getContext(), BluetoothService.class);
                service.putExtra("MAC", mac);
                service.putExtra("MESSAGE", "VOL_DOWN");
                vib.vibrate(50);
                startService(service);
            }});

        Button btn_Mute = (Button) findViewById (R.id.vol_Mute);
        btn_Mute.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                Intent service = new Intent(v.getContext(), BluetoothService.class);
                service.putExtra("MAC", mac);
                service.putExtra("MESSAGE", "MUTE");
                vib.vibrate(100);
                startService(service);
            }});




        mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             Log.i(getPackageName(), "Got Intent");
             String volume=intent.getStringExtra("DATA");
             Double volume_dbl = Double.valueOf(volume);
             volume_dbl=volume_dbl*100;
             int volume_int=(int)Math.round(volume_dbl);
             txt.setText(String.valueOf(volume_int));
             progress.setProgress(volume_int);
            }
        };


        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("DataAvialable"));
    }






    public void setProgressBarState(String daten) {
        try {

        txt.setText(daten);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(getPackageName(), daten, e);  
        }
            }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
       super.onResume();
       Log.i(getPackageName(), "onResume");

    }






    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        Log.i(getPackageName(), "onPause");
        //stopService(service);

    }

    }
```

Comment: can you add a stacktrace?

Comment: which is line number 67 in BluetoohService.java? Are you sure that the daten String in OnCreate() is non null ? Try logging the value maybe.

Comment: You're not checking if `daten` is `null`.

Comment: Number 67 is "remote.setProgressBarState(daten);" This daten-String is not null, on debugging mode, i see correct values of "daten"

Comment: What is txt? Is it textView? You say that you are getting InvocationTargetException if you are trying to find the textview with the given ID. That exception occurs when there is not textview in the XML file that you are targeting. We would be able to help if you could post the class and the related xml file.

Comment: The id should be right, if I try to get it in onCreate(), everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said that InvocationTargetException occurs if you are trying to find the textview with the given ID which does not exist. In your layout file the text view ID is "textView2" with a small 't'. But you are trying to find a textView with ID "TextView2". They are both different ID's. So try to use the following:

```
 TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2);
 txt.setText(daten);
```

Hope it helps.

**Update**

If the value of daten inside the setProgressBarState() function as is non null, then the problem can be that you are creating an object of 'RemoteControl' Class inside your handler. If you try to instantiate an Activity by normal means ( MyActivity ma = new MyActivity(); ) then onCreate() method WILL NOT be called. So it might not be able to find the TextView.

You can try to accomplish your task by another way. You can save the Value in SharedPreference and then when user instantiate the activity get that value from SharedPreferences again and show it to user.

Comment: I edited my method to public void setProgressBarState(String daten) {
  
  TextView txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
  txt.setText(daten);
  
 } but get java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: If the value of daten inside the setProgressBarState() function as is non null, then the problem can be that you are creating an object of 'RemoteControl' Class inside your handler. if you try to instantiate an Activity by normal means ( MyActivity ma = new MyActivity(); ) then onCreate() method WILL NOT be called. Only if you start the Activity with an intent will the method be called. So, it might not be able to find the TextView of txt. You might try and have " TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2); " defined inside the setProgressBarState() try{}

Comment: That means, if I create an object from an Activity to call the method setProgressBarState(), "TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2); cannot be resolved, because in this case, Android do not have "the link" to the XML... and cannot find the textView2... and so i get an IvocationTargetException.... is this right? and how can i fix this?

Comment: Did you try and put TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2); " inside the setProgressBarState() function's try{} ? I'm not sure of it but worth a try.

Comment: yes, see my first comment on your answer... I kicked the try out to get a better look at the Exception in debug mode...

Comment: okay. My apologies. There are many posts on how to set a TextView from another activity. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672372/android-set-text-views-text-from-another-activity-not-working and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206181/want-to-change-text-of-textview-from-other-activity . Another way is you can save the Value in SharedPreference and then when user instantiate the activity get that value from SharedPreferences again.